# iOS 7 simulator can't run BLE?

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios-simulator, xcode5

iOS 6 can use simulator to run BLE for debug.

But when I upgrade to Xcode5, the iOS 7 simulator without bluetooth switch.

So,I can't run BLE on iOS7 simulator.

Is that a only way to load the program on iphone to test the BLE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes correct. This was discussed in the Core Bluetooth 2013 WWDC video. Effective iOS7, you need to run your app on a physical device to test BLE.

Comment: Is the limitation imposed by the SDK, XCODE or the Simulator.  In other words I am currently using Xcode 4.x with iOS6.  If I switch to iOS 7 - will the BLE in simulator stop working for iOS7 or for iOS6 as well.

Comment: The video mentioned by Spectravideo is session #703 at https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/index.php?id=703 and the bit about the simulator starts right around 6:00.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode Simulator not support BLE, need to real/physical ios device.